# How to color part of android text if edittext contains that word

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to color a word (house) as long as user types "house" in the edittext. This is what I've done:

```
if (textA.getText().toString().equals("house")){
    String name = String.valueOf(textA.getText().toString().equals("house"));
    name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
}
```

my xml is as follows

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="5dp">


                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/textA"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:maxLines ="4"
                        android:maxLength ="2000"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/grey"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:gravity="top"/>

                </LinearLayout>
```

however this causes the app to crash. Dont know what it is I'm doing wrong. I'm new to android. Any advice please?

Comment: What does the LogCat say? What is the crash error?

Comment: You should get compile time error for `name.setTextColor` as name is string(local var)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this works for me

```
 textA.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String str="home";
            Spannable spannable =textA.getText();
            if(s.length() != 0) {
                textA.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));
                ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan( Color.GREEN);
                String s1 = s.toString();
                int in=0; // start searching from 0 index

// keeps on searching unless there is no more function string found
                while ((in = s1.indexOf(str,in)) >= 0) {
                    spannable.setSpan(
                            fcs,
                            in,
                            in + str.length(),
                            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    // update the index for next search with length
                    in += str.length();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: works but color change applies to all text. how can we make this apply to only "home" whiles the other colors remain normal?

Comment: means in edittext only "home" word should contain different colour?

Comment: exactly. cant seem to figure this out

Comment: wait, will let you know with answer

Comment: update answer. actually, in my code, I use data binding that's why.

Comment: you sir are a genius! One last question then this will be perfect, what if I want to apply the highlight to multiple text: "home", "office", "chair"

Comment: any luck yet please?

Comment: yes I just posted this. Now I don't know how to merge this with what we've already achieved

Comment: then what happens to s1?

Comment: wait I will help you

Comment: when you replace code, it works but buggy. If you type last string first before typing first string, it doesn't work

Comment: any solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

You have to write code like below

```
 textA.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {} @Override public void
 beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
 @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int
 before, int count) {
      if(s.length() != 0 && s.contains("home"))  name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
    });
```

Comment: It may be syntax errors because i post it from mobile.

Comment: can you help me out please?

Comment: cannot resolve s; cannot resolve setTextColor; cannot resolve parseColor

Answer (score 0):

equals return values is boolean.
so you have to change it.

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject)

  if (textA.getText().toString().equals("house")){
      textA.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
    }
```